# Norm in a vector space of all convergent sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $c_o$ be the vector space of all convergent sequences $x = (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$. Let $\lVert x \rVert = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x \rvert$

Show that for $x \in c_0 \ \ \exists k \ \ s.t. \ \lvert x_k \rvert = \lVert x \rVert_{\infty}$

I'm confused about the question a little bit. Is this asking to show that there is a value of $x_n$ that attains the max of x?

Additionally, is this norm called the "Uniform Norm"?

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: Hint: for a general sequence, can you describe situations where $|x_k| = \|x\|_\infty$ fails to hold for all $k$? Why do the conditions on $c_0$ prevent these situations from happening?

Comment: Almost. You have to show that there is some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|x_n| = \|x\|$ (note the absolute value). Yes, this is called the uniform norm or supremum norm. Hint: if the sequence is not identically zero, then $\|x\| > 0$. In that case, show that $|x_n| < \|x\|/2$ if you go sufficiently far out in the sequence (say $n > N$), so the supremum is really the max of the finite set $\{|x_1|, |x_2|, \ldots, |x_N|\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ were the zero sequence, nothing to prove. Assume that some $x_{n_{0}}\ne 0$, and find some $N>n_{0}$ such that $n>N$, $|x_{n}|<|x_{n_{0}}|/2$. Now $\sup_{n}|x_{n}|=\max\{\max_{1\leq n\leq N}|x_{n}|,\sup_{n>N}|x_{n}|\}=\max_{1\leq n\leq N}|x_{n}|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n=0$ for all $n$ then you are done. Otherwise there must exist some $n_0$ such that $|x_{n_0}|>0$. Since $\lim_nx_n=0$ there is $N$ such that $|x_n|<|x_{n_0}|$ if $n>N$. Thus $||x||_\infty=\max_{n\leq N}|x_n|=|x_{n_1}|$ for some $n_1\leq N$.